# GridGain Out of Memory Exception

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory, gridgain

I am trying to load around 600MB of data in the GridGain cache, I am trying to use the Swap Space to reduce the load on my RAM. I am loading the data from CSV files. I load the first 10000 keys in the memory then load the rest in the swap space. I was able to load 1350000 keys, but after that I am getting the below error :

```
[16:58:34,701][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#54%null%][GridWorker] Runtime error caught during grid runnable execution: GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, gridName=null, finished=false, isCancelled=false, hashCode=20495511, interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#54%null%]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:559)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:851)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:484)
    .
    .
    .
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

GridGain node stopped OK [uptime=00:21:14:384]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are clearly running out of Heap space. In order for swap space to get utilized, you should configure eviction policy. Please refer to [OffHeap Memory](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG619/Off-Heap+Memory) documentation for more information on how to configure Swap and OffHeap spaces.

Also, there is some more explanation for memory utilization in this post: [Can I reduce the space of my cache memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692393/can-i-reduce-the-space-of-my-cache-memory)